# Show that $f'(y) = 0$ when $f$ has a local maximum at $y$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function. For some given $y \in (0,1)$, $\exists$ $\epsilon > 0$ such that $$f(x) \leq f(y) \ \forall \ x \in (y-\epsilon, y+\epsilon).$$ Show that $f'(y) = 0$.

I have a rough idea that if $f'(y) \neq 0$, then $\exists \ \theta \in (y-\epsilon, y+\epsilon)$ such that $f(\theta) > f(y)$ (where $\theta > y$ if $f'(y) > 0$ and $\theta < y$ if $f'(y) < 0$) which is not possible. I can vizualize this. But I don't know how to show this formally.

Comment: This is a very basic fact proved in any Calculus book. If $f$ has local extremum at a point and if it is differentiable at that point then the derivative is $0$.

Comment: ...provided that (like in your case) $f$ is defined on both sides of that point.

Comment: @geetha290krm I added a proof. Can you please check and tell me if it's correct or I need to add something for more rigour?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out how to do this. Note that

$f'(x) \big\vert_{x = y} = \underset{x \to y}{\lim} \dfrac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}\;$ such that :

1. $\underset{x \to y^{+}}{\lim} \dfrac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \geq 0$
2. $\underset{x \to y^{-}}{\lim} \dfrac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \leq 0$

Since the derivative exists, $f'(y) = 0$.

Comment: Your proof is correct but is a duplicate (mutatis mutandis).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f'(y)>0\,.$

According to the definition of derivative, we have that

$\dfrac{f(\theta)-f(y)}{\theta-y}>0\;,\quad\forall\,\theta\in (y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)\setminus\{y\}$.

Then when $\theta>y,$ we have $f(\theta)>f(y)\,$; whereas $f(\theta)<f(y)$ when $\theta<y$, contradicting with the local maximum.

Analogously, also assuming that $\,f’(y)<0\,,\;$ leads to a contradiction.

Hence, $\,f’(y)=0\,.$

Comment: Can you please explain the "according to definition of derivative, we have [..]" part?

Comment: Derivative is defined by the fraction.When $\theta$ is sufficiently close to y,the ratio will$> 0$.It is enough to discuss the size of $\theta$ and $y$ on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Your proof by contradiction is correct but I find the direct one simpler. Moreover, this whole post is a duplicate.